# Mysql+auth plugin - logging external username

Tags: mysql, authentication

When using an an auth plugin (specifically pam) does the general query log record the external username for connections?

Comment: Which version of MySQL/MariaDB and the plugin?

Comment: @Rick: are you saying this has changed?

Comment: The auth plugin is relatively new.  As such, there may have been fixes soon thereafter.